# HCF of two algebraic expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question came up in an exam and has been bugging me for a long time, since there appears to be no apparent solution to me:

> What's the HCF of these algebraic expressions?

$2x^2 - 6x$, $2x^2 - 7x + 3$

I was given the choices

> A. $x(x-3)$
>
> B. $2(x-3)$
>
> C. $x-3$
>
> D. $2x$

It would be very helpful if someone is able to explain this. Thank you for your time!

Comment: They're $2x(x-3)$ and $(2x-1)(x-3)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner My bad. The exam happens to be an objective question and I was given the choices $x(x-3)$, $2(x-3)$, $(x-3)$, $2x$.

I've added these choices into the question.

Comment: Easy enough to note that HCF of two numbers will divide their difference as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the highest common factor $x-3$ by looking at the factorizations

$2x^2-6x=2x(x-3)$ and $2x^2-7x+3=(2x-1)(x-3)$.

You could also find it using the Euclidean algorithm:

$2x^2-6x=1(2x^2-7x+3)+(x-3)$

$2x^2-7x+3=(2x-1)(x-3)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. Great explanation. However, we were requested to calculate the HCF of two equations all at once in my particular case, and was given only the four choices (listed in the question).

Comment: >  Hi, thanks again. Great explanation. However, we were requested to calculate the HCF of two equations all at once in my particular case, and was given only the four choices (listed in the question). – Jeff White 24 secs ago     

In this case, are the answers even valid?

Comment: I would choose C